# Does a reference in a shallow copy effect the changes by the original copy on the new copy?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I'm trying to understand the difference between the shallow copy, deep copy, and assignment operator.  Compounding to the confusion is the conflicting articles like [this](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-deep-copy-objects-and-arrays-in-javascript-7c911359b089) and [this](https://markoskon.com/deep-copy-vs-shallow-copy-vs-assignment/).  From what I understand, the key point in understanding the two concepts is the reference, whether you're copying the actual value or copying just the reference of the value.

The first article makes a distinction between "one level" and "nested", saying that "a shallow copy refers to the fact that only one level is copied" and a deep copy is "objects and arrays containing other objects or arrays".  His version of one level includes a non-nested array, like `const arr = [1, 2, 3]`.

The second article makes a distinction between a primitive and non-primitive. So the category would be something like a string vs an array.

The former article contends that when a shallow copy is made from the "one level" array (as opposed to the nested array), a new reference is created. And when a reference is created, the changes in the original will not effect the copied array. For example,

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
const newArr = [...arr]
arr[0] = 100
console.log(newArr) // [1, 2, 3]
```

The second article contends that when a reference is created, the new copy and the old copy points to the same address, and changing one of them will effect both of them. The example he gave was for the assignment operator:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
const newArr = arr
arr[0] = 100
console.log(newArr) // [100, 2, 3]
```

I understand that the first example is a spread operator and the second is an assignment operator, but when it comes to a reference being the cause of effecting the new copy are totally opposite. So does a reference cause the new copy to be effected by the changes in the original copy or not?

Comment: in the second example, `newArr` isn't a copy, its a reference to `arr`. so there has been no "copying".

Comment: is `newArr` in the first example not a reference then?

Comment: no, because you are using the spread operator to copy the items in `arr` into a new array, which is assigned to `newArr`. However, if the values in the array are non primitives, `newArr` will contain references to those  same non-primitives from `arr`, so mutating the non primitive in either array will result in the non primitive being modified in both arrays.

Comment: ok so does that mean the spread operator doesn't create a new reference and therefore a shallow copy doesn't create a new reference since a spread operator is a shallow copy? I thought a shallow copy creates a reference and a deep copy copies the value

Comment: spread operator doesn't create new references in the first example. the new reference is created when you define the new array with `[]`. the spread is just copying the items from the array into the new array. to deep clone, you will need to recursively copy all non primitive values (arrays, objects) etc.

Comment: I see, so is it safe to say that a shallow copy doesn't create a reference, it just copies the values? And changing the old copy doesn't effect the new copy?

Comment: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-8-evaluation-strategy/#call-by-sharing

Comment: a shallow copy creates a new object with the properties copied from the original object. if those properties at the 1st level are primitive, they are copy by value. if they are non primitives, then the reference is copied by value as well, but its a reference pointing to the same object. if you are confused, welcome to javascript. the language is very confusing and this is one of the biggest problems.

Comment: @Teemu thanks for the article. It says that there's a difference between a "implicit reference" and "a copy of the reference". Could you elaborate?

Comment: Let's say that there's an object X somewhere in the memory. A copy of the reference to the object is like a map you can look to find the road to the object. An implicit reference is the road itself. If you delete the map, the object is still at the end of the road, but if you delete the road, you can't reach the object anymore. Maybe a bit poor analogy ...

Comment: I think I I kind of get it. So relating back to my question, would the shallow copy be creating the copy of a reference where the modifying, or deleting the road as your analogy, doesn't effect the copy of the original?

Comment: JS never handles the roads, it uses the maps only. Shallow copy only copies the references, a deep copy in JS practically creates new objects.